# Can you run an installed Xbox 360 game off of USB flash drives now?

Tags: xbox-360

Since you can use USB Flash Drives for data storage now, is it possible to install a game to one? Or, can you install to HDD and then copy to flash drive?

Unfortunately I'm one of those with an old 20GB HDD...so before I go buying a USB stick or two rather than a bigger HDD, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that you can install a game to a USB drive, since I've (accidentally) done it before. The Xbox allows me to select either the internal hard drive or the attached USB drive, after I select to install the game.

I haven't tried to run a game installed to the USB drive (since I accidentally installed it there), but given that it allows you to install a game to it, I don't see why it wouldn't allow you to do so.

I don't know if you can copy installed games, though. I'd lean towards not, but I haven't tried to do so (and I can't check right now, since I'm at work).

Comment: Yes, you can install and run them from the USB device. You can also move them from Hard Drive to USB and vice-versa.

Comment: Hmm...wonder if running it off of flash drive is slower than HDD...

Comment: I would imagine it depends on the performance of the USB drive itself. I run all my XBLA games off the USB with no issues, except for Deathspank. Whenever is auto-saves it causes issues with the performance. I've not seen any other XBLA games have issues though. I have not tried a full-size game as my 16gb drive is pretty full.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but the drive has to be larger than 6GB because the installation takes up to 6GB of space.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can no longer install games to a USB using the new dashboard (Or at least I cannot with the 250 GB xbox 360 slim) the reason I tried was because apparently there used to be a way to play without disk (Install to USB) but I couldnt select USB (There was no option) and it wouldn't allow me to move or copy it from the storage option in settings...

Answer (score 0):

I copied Bully onto my USB and installed everything on the USB to his xbox, and he was able to play the game just fine. Tip: you have to keep the USB plugged in when playing the game