# How to use external hard drive with my xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could I use a 1/2TB USB 2/3 external HDD with an XBox 360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78314/could-i-use-a-1-2tb-usb-2-3-external-hdd-with-an-xbox-360)

I formatted an external hard drive as fat32, and divided it into many 16GB partions.
Now when I connected it my xbox, it recognized just about 32GB,
How to make it recognize all the drives?

and also while downloading something from xbox apps, it is not asking me if I want to save on xbox or the external hard, is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of extra 'volumes' is 2. Either 2 additional USB thumb drives, or 2 logical 32GB drives on a single hard drive.