# How to provide more room in a Xbox 360 Slim for Call of Duty Black Ops III?

Tags: xbox-360

I just received Call of Duty: Black Ops 3 on my Xbox 360 Slim,

The storage capacity is 4GB, but the game requires 8GB.

How can I make room to play it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "make room" because there isn't enough room on the disk to store it. You can however buy an [external hard drive](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1107717-can-i-add-a-hard-drive-to-the-xbox-360-4gb-model/). An external hard drive is an additional disk drive that you buy and connect to your Xbox. This allows the Xbox to store data on the disk and therefore increases its storage capacity. However, provided you don't install the game onto your Xbox, and simply insert the CD every time you want to play the game, you don't have to go to any extra expense at all.

Comment: I read somewhere else you can do it with a USB drive too?

Comment: [Certainly](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10638/can-you-run-an-installed-xbox-360-game-off-of-usb-flash-drives-now)

Comment: What kind of USB drive does it have to be?

Comment: I sound stupid but I never have had this problem before.

Comment: I am lead to understand it can be any USB 2.0 and above flash drive.

Comment: I just have an 8gb usb drive.

Comment: As far as I know that should be just fine.

Comment: I've tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I guess I was wrong - you may need a different USB drive. Google will probably be your friend here; I don't know what drives are compatible with Xbox.

Comment: you can not simply plug a USB flash drive in. It still requires the Xbox to format the drive into a container it understands for handling games. The xbox can do it, but I do not recall the exact process

Comment: As others have stated, you'll have to let the console format the USB stick first. Also, it may be worth noting that an Xbox can only read a USB stick with a size of up to 32GB as stated here: http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/accessories/using-usb-flash-drive

Comment: Usb 3.0 is best for installing games.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should buy a flash drive for on-the-go storage, in case you want to take it to a buddy's house or something. Just plug it in to the USB ports, and that's about it.